# LDAP + TLS - different behaviour on two machines

Tags: linux, ldap, perl, tls, sles

machines:

1. debian wheezy
2. suse 11

commands:

1. `ldapsearch -ZZ -h ad.unsw.edu.au -x`
2. `perl -we "use Net::LDAP; print Net::LDAP->new ('ad.unsw.edu.au')->start_tls(verify => 'require', capath => '/etc/ssl/certs/')->{errorMessage}"`

results:

- machine 1, command 1: TLS: hostname does not match CN in peer certificate
- machine 1, command 2: works
- machine 2, command 1: works
- machine 2, command 2: Cannot determine peer hostname for verification

i can't explain the inconsistency and i really want command 2 to work on machine 2.  any ideas?

after an strace, it looks like debian-ldapsearch is looking at `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` and suse-ldapsearch is looking at NOTHING.  debian-`Net::LDAP` is looking at `/etc/ssl/certs/157753a5.?` (`AddTrust_External_Root.pem`) and suse-`Net::LDAP` is looking at NOTHING.

Comment: FYI, setting `verify='none'` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line 233 of `Net/LDAP.pm` in `Net::LDAP` 0.43 says

```
SSL_verifycn_scheme => "ldap",
```

debian wheezy is using 0.40, but upgrading to 0.43 from unstable breaks it as well.

https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=70795

Answer (score 1):

You should check that the remote SSL certificate has "CN" part of the subject same as the hostname of the LDAPS server in your commands (ad.unsw.edu.au).

To see the remote certificate use:

```
echo ""|openssl s_client -connect ad.unsw.edu.au:636 |openssl x509 -noout -subject -dates -issuer
```

Full details:

```
echo ""|openssl s_client -connect ad.unsw.edu.au:636 |openssl x509 -noout -text
```

Check that the issuer's root certificate is imported and trusted in the ldap (see [OpenLDAP SSL](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin23/tls.html) documentation) and perl SSL keystore (see [IO::Socket::SSL](http://search.cpan.org/~sullr/IO-Socket-SSL-1.49/SSL.pm)). If it is a selfsign certificate, then that certificate should be added to the trusted SSL keychain.

Comment: Interesting paths to openssl client, considering @Jayen seems to have Linux environment. I can see your Solaris-Fu is strong. :-)

Comment: Yes :). I have a strong feeling that the /usr/sfw is missing in Linux. I will edit my answer.

Comment: yup: `echo -n | openssl s_client -connect ad.unsw.edu.au:636 | openssl verify -CAfile /tmp/COMODOHigh-AssuranceSecureServerCA.crt`  thanks!

Comment: er no.  even after installing the certificate, perl & ldapsearch aren't picking it up and the results are still the same.

Comment: Use `strace` to see which file is trying to use perl and ldapsearch. Make sure they are reading the trusted certificated keychain.

Comment: perl behavior matches that of ldapsearch.  (editing question with the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Net::LDAP::start_tls() is broken in perl-ldap-0.43.  Your command-line should work fine if you upgrade to 0.44 or later.  This is documented in the Changes file:

http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MARSCHAP/perl-ldap-0.44/Changes

```
Bug Fixes
 * un-break certificate verification
```

Comment: thanks for that.  i found a fix in github, and i wonder why they didn't release 0.44 sooner.

https://github.com/perl-ldap/perl-ldap/pull/3